# Dataframe Slice does not remove Index Values

Tags: python, pandas

I recently had this issue with a large dataframe and its associated multi index. 
This simplified example will demonstrate the issue.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B'],[5,6]])


df = pd.DataFrame(data= np.random.randint(1,100,(4)),index= idx,columns =['P'])
print df
```

Which yields:

```
      P
A 5  38
  6  13
B 5  73
  6  10
```

Now take a quick look at the index

```
print df.index

MultiIndex(levels=[[u'A', u'B'], [5, 6]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

If I slice this dataframe I notice that the multi index never condenses.
Even with a deep copy.

What is the best way to reduce the memory footprint of the index in a slice operation?

```
df_slice = df[df['P']>20]
print df_slice
print df_slice.index

      P
A 5  38
B 5  73
```

See how the dataframe has reduced, but the index has not.

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'A', u'B'], [5, 6]],
           labels=[[0, 1], [0, 0]])
```

Even with a .copy(deep=True)

```
df_slice = df[df['P']>20].copy(deep=True)
print df_slice.index


MultiIndex(levels=[[u'A', u'B'], [5, 6]]
    ,labels=[[0, 1], [0, 0]])
```

I would have expected MultiIndex to have the 6 removed as shown:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'A', u'B'], [5]]
    ,labels=[[0, 1], [0, 0]])
```

The issue comes in practice when the dataframe is large.

Comment: Same goes when I drop some rows from the dataframe. One would expect if the rows were removed, why would the index retain those values!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand your concern, but I believe you have to see what is happening in pandas low-level application.

First, we must declare that indexes are supposed to be immutable. You can check more of its documentation here -> http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-metadata

When you create a dataframe object, let's name it `df` and you want to access its rows, basically all you do is passing a boolean series that Pandas will match with its corresponding index.

Follow this example:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B'],[5,6]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(1,100,(4)), index=index, columns=["P"])

      P
A 5   5
  6  51
B 5  93
  6  76
```

Now, let's say we want to select the rows with *P > 90*. How would you do that? `df[df["P"] > 90]`, right? But look at what df["P"] > 90 actually returns.

```
A  5     True
   6     True
B  5     True
   6    False
Name: P, dtype: bool
```

As you can see, it returns a boolean series matching the original index. Why? Because Pandas needs to map which index values have an equivalent true value, so it can select the proper outcome. So basically, during your slice opperations, you will always carry this index, because it is a mapping element for the object.

However, hope is not gone. Depending on your application, if you believe it is actually taking a huge portion of your memory, you can spend a little time doing the following:

```
def df_sliced_index(df):
    new_index = []
    rows = []
    for ind, row in df.iterrows():
        new_index.append(ind)
        rows.append(row)
    return pd.DataFrame(data=rows, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_index))

df_sliced_index(df[df['P'] > 90]).index
```

Which yields what I believe, is the desired output:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'B'], [5]], labels=[[0], [0]])
```

But if data is too large to worry you about the size of index, I wonder how much it may cost you in terms of time.

Comment: Ricardo -Your answer is helpful - Thanks. I think you have a little 90 v 30 typo.

Comment: Thanks - you gave me the necessary insight. However, I think i would avoid the iterrows() and after the slicing operation then do a .reset_index() followed immediately by a .set_index(). That results in the multi index having a reduced footprint.

Comment: Oh yes, it was a typo. First I wrote the code for bigger than 30, but then it returned all the values. About reseting the index, I thought you needed it multiindex as they were. But okay, I am glad I could help somehow.

Comment: Thanks @RicardoSilveira for the explanation. Is there a way to get just the index of the current filtered / extracted / queried / dropped dataframe? I work in Data Analysis and Visualization, and I prepare multiple outputs from a single dataframe by preparing multiple slices from the same df. Now, to visualize the data, I need to use the index as a base. But every time I do df_slide.index it gives me all the indices from the original index. Instead, I would like if I can just get the index that are part of the df_slice. Is it possible through some other function or method?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the MultiIndex unique by

```
df_slice.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df_slice.index.unique(), names=idx.names)
```

which yields the index

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'A', u'B'], [5]],
           labels=[[0, 1], [0, 0]])
```

Comment: Thanks - that will work. I still wonder why it has not fundamentally changed.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way to do this is

```
old_idx = df_slice.index
new_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(old_idx.to_series(), names=old_idx.names)
```