# pandas multiindex selecting...how to get the right (restricted to selection) index

Tags: python, pandas, select, multi-index

I am struggeling to get the right (restricted to the selection) index when using the methode [xs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) by pandas to select specific data in my dataframe. Let me demonstrate, what I am doing:

```
print(df)
                                                             value
idx1              idx2          idx3         idx4  idx5            
10                2.0           0.0010          1     2        6.0  ...   
                                                2     3        6.0  ...   
...
                                                7     8        6.0  ...   
                                                8     9        6.0  ...  
20                2.0           0.0010          1     2        6.0  ...  
                                                2     3        6.0  ...  
...
                                                18    19       6.0  ...  
                                                19    20       6.0  ...  

# get dataframe for idx1 = 10, idx2 = 2.0, idx3 = 0.0010 
print(df.xs([10,2.0,0.0010]))

             value
idx4  idx5            
1     2        6.0  ...   
2     3        6.0  ...   
3     4        6.0  ...     
4     5        6.0  ...     
5     6        6.0  ...     
6     7        6.0  ...     
7     8        6.0  ...   
8     9        6.0  ...  

# get the first index list of this part of the dataframe
print(df.xs([10,2.0,0.0010]).index.levels[0])

[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,18, 19]
```

So I do not understand, why the full list of values that occur in idx4 is returned even though we restricted the dataframe to a part where idx4 only takes values from 1 to 8. Is it that I use the [index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.html) method in a wrong way?

Comment: look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585009/dataframe-slice-does-not-remove-index-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known **feature** not bug.  pandas preserves all of the index information.  You can determine which of the levels are expressed and at what location via the `labels` attribute.

If you are looking to create an index that is fresh and just contains the information relevant to the slice you just made, you can do this:

```
df_new = df.xs([10,2.0,0.0010])
idx_new = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df_new.index.to_series(),
                                    names=df_new.index.names)
df_new.index = idx_new
```