# pandas.DataFrame.query keeping original multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataframe with multiindex:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,(6, 2)), columns=['col1','col2'])
>>> df['ind1'] = list('AAABCC')
>>> df['ind2'] = range(6)
>>> df.set_index(['ind1','ind2'], inplace=True)

>>> df
           col1  col2
ind1 ind2            
A    0        2     0
     1        2     2
     2        1     2
B    3        2     2
C    4        4     0
     5        1     4
```

when I select data using `.loc[]` on one of the index levels, and apply `.query()` afterwards, resulting index is "shrinked" as expected to match only those values contained in resulting dataframe:

```
>>> df.loc['A'].query('col2 == 2')

      col1  col2
ind2            
1        2     2
2        1     2

>>> df.loc['A'].query('col2 == 2').index

Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64', name='ind2')
```

however when I try to recieve same result using just `.query()`, pandas keeps the same index as on original dataframe (despite the fact, that it didn't behave like that above, in the case of single index - resulting index went from `[0,1,2]` to `[1,2]`, matching only `col2 == 2` rows):

```
>>> df.query('ind1 == "A" & col2 == 2')

           col1  col2
ind1 ind2            
A    1        2     2
     2        1     2

>>> df.query('ind1 == "A" & col2 == 2').index

MultiIndex(levels=[['A', 'B', 'C'], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],
           labels=[[0, 0], [1, 2]],
           names=['ind1', 'ind2'])
```

is it a bug or a feature? if feature, could you please explain such behavior?

EDIT1:
I would expect following index instead:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['A'], [1, 2]],
           labels=[[0, 0], [0, 1]],
           names=['ind1', 'ind2'])
```

EDIT2:
as explained in [Dataframe Slice does not remove Index Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585009/dataframe-slice-does-not-remove-index-values) index values shouldn't be removed at all when slicing DF; such behavior should give following result:

```
>>> df.loc['A'].query('col2 == 2')

      col1  col2
ind2            
1        2     2
2        1     2

>>> df.loc['A'].query('col2 == 2').index

EXPECTATION: Int64Index([0, 1, 2], dtype='int64', name='ind2')
REALITY:     Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64', name='ind2')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dataframe Slice does not remove Index Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585009/dataframe-slice-does-not-remove-index-values)

Answer (score 1):

`df.loc[A]` returns you a DF (or a "view") with a regular ("single") index:

```
In [12]: df.loc['A']
Out[12]:
      col1  col2
ind2
0        1     1
1        0     3
2        1     2
```

so `.query()` will be applied on that DF with a regular index...

Comment: but that still doesn't explain the behavior. `.query()` applied on that DF with regular index does "shrink" the index, which doesn't happen in the case of multiindex...

Comment: it's `.loc[]` who shrinks (selects one level) the index and not a `query()`

Comment: @kekert, you didn't write in your question - what is wrong with `df.query('ind1 == "A" & col2 == 2')`?

Comment: by "shrinking" I don't mean removing a level from the index, but selecting only those index entries which match rows in resulting dataframe. see my comment above - resulting index went from `[0,1,2]` to `[1,2]`, matching only `col2 == 2` rows

Comment: @kekert, now i'm totally confused! What would you expect as a result of: `df.query('ind1 == "A" & col2 == 2')` ?

Comment: @ MaxU sry, its my bad english most likely. I have edited the question with my "expected result"